# Is $0\bar{.9}$ in $[0,1)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, decimal-expansion

> Is $0\bar{.9}$ in $[0,1)$?

$0\bar{.9} = 1$, so does that mean $0\bar{.9} \notin [0,1)$?

What about

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} 1/n^2 = 0$$
is this in $(0,1]$?

Or are these two separate concepts? If so, please help me understand them.

Comment: Well, $\;0.\overline 9=1\;$ , so it isn't in $\;[0,1)\;$ . Also, the limit of $\;\frac1{n^2}\;$ when $\;n\to\infty\;$ isn't in $\;(0,1]\;$ ...I'm not sure what's the problem here, perhaps I didn't understand.

Comment: Clearly you agree that $1\notin [0,1)$. So if you doubt the same for $0.\overline{9}$, then you are likely not completely comfortable with $0.\overline{9}=1$. Maybe you should try to find the "difference" betwenn $0.\overline{9}$ and $1$. However, in standard analysis there is no difference. If at all the difference is smaller than any positive real number, but that is non standard analysis.

Comment: A limit of a sequence all lying in some interval can leave that interval, which happens in these examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sequence is not its limit. Sequences need not even have a limit.

But even a convergent sequence is *not* its limit. It's true, intuitively we think about continuity *everywhere* (until this wrong intuition is uprooted by the myriad of examples).

Since you are thinking about $0.\overline 9$ as the limit of $0.9, 0.99, 0.999,\dots$ and all of these are clearly are members of $[0,1)$, but the limit need not be in the set. Not without additional hypotheses (e.g. closure).

The answer is similar about $0$ in $(0,1]$.

What *is* true, is that $1$ is a limit point of $[0,1)$, exactly because it is in the limit of the sequence $0.9,0.99,0.999,\ldots$; and similarly $0$ is a limit point of $(0,1]$ since it is the limit of $\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots$

But as neither $[0,1)$ nor $(0,1]$ are *closed*, there is no reason for them to contain all their limit points.

Comment: Ok, the last line reminded me of just what "open" means. I had confused limiting processes with the limits themselves. Thank you.

Comment: You're very much welcomed!

Answer (score 5):

If two things are equal, that means they are *literally exactly the same thing in every possible way*.  So, $0.\bar{9} = 1$ means that $0.\bar{9}$ and $1$ are identical: they're just two different sequence of symbols we can use to refer to the *same* number.  So, since $1\not\in[0,1)$, $0.\bar{9}\not\in[0,1)$ as well.  Similarly, $\lim_{n\to \infty} 1/n^2$ is not in $(0,1]$, since it is equal to $0$.

The key point here is that the limit refers *only* to the final answer, not to the "process" of getting there.  So, if you want to determine whether something is true of a limit, you *only* care about what number the limit is.  The numbers you used to *approach* the limit are completely irrelevant.

The following analogy may be helpful.  Suppose Alice has one brother, whose name is Bob.  Suppose someone comes up to you and asks whether Alice's brother has brown hair.  To determine this, you would want to look at Bob and see if he has brown hair.  You wouldn't want to look at Alice's hair!  In the same way, if someone asks you whether $\lim_{n\to \infty} 1/n^2$ is in $(0,1]$, you want to look at the value of the limit.  You don't want to look at the value of the numbers $1/n^2$.  The limit is defined in terms of those numbers, just as "Alice's brother" is defined in terms of "Alice", but the limit is just as distinct an entity from them as Bob is from Alice.

Comment: Unfortunately most beginners are interested in Alice than Bob :) :) and somehow try to see the sequence and the limit with the same eye. A limit is related to the sequence but it is fundamentally a different thing than the sequence. I hope your example at the end helps to convince many people. +1

Answer (score 1):

The interval $[0,1)$ is open at the right end  therefore  $$0\bar{.9} =1 \notin [0,1)$$

Similarly $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} 1/n^2 = 0 \notin (0,1],$$ because the interval $(0,1] $ does not include $0.$

That is a good way to define closed sets in general.

If the limit of every convergent sequence is in the set then the set is closed.

Thus none of $[0,1)$ or $(0,1]$ is closed.

Comment: Got it. You have helped me understand how to read open and closed sets, which I had a little confused.